# Why the whole object cannot be observed to vibrate when energy is transferred through conduction (solid)?

Tags: thermal-conductivity

Conduction is the transfer of thermal energy when particles in an object vibrate and collide with neighbouring particles thereby transferring their kinetic energy to them, why doesn't the whole object vibrate?

Comment: At room temperature, say, the atoms oscillate on the order of $10^{-10}$ m, which is too small for you to directly observe. Furthermore, the atoms of the material are not all oscillating synchronously (if they did then that would violate the conservation of momentum).

Comment: @lemon: That's an answer, I believe.